# Android 8.1 Keyboard on Galaxy Tab A doesn't display word choices

Tags: settings, keyboard, samsung-galaxy-tab, 8.1-oreo

My old Samsung Galaxy Tab running Android 4.2 would always show 3 word suggestions above the keyboard as I was typing. I thought it was very helpful. But my new tablet(Galaxy Tab A 8") running 8.1 doesn't have that. Can I get that back?

Answer (score 2):

Let it be set to default keyboard(Samsung Keyboard).

Follow steps to turn on word's suggestions:

**For Galaxy tab:**

Follow the steps:

1. Open Settings - Scroll down to System - Language and input-Choose Samsung keyboard.
2. Under Smart typing choose *Predictive text* and enable it.

**For Handsets:**

1. Open Settings-General Managment-Language and Input-On screen keyboard-Samsung Keyboard.
2. Now turn on 'Predictive text' option and again in this option turn of 'Auto replace'.

Note: *Auto Replace* will enable the keyboard to replace predicted words by itself and this could create problem while typing.

Answer (score 0):

Downloaded the [Google keyboard app](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.inputmethod.latinand). It solved the problem for me

Comment: You can return after 48 hours to [accept the answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer).Thanks for self answering